# Ruby - Remove 1 or 2 character from a string to make it a palindrome

Tags: ruby, palindrome

I had a technical test for an entry-level job 2 days ago. It went well apart from the last assessment.
I will go over the assessment with the CTO tomorrow and was hoping I could get help to get my head around this one, so I do not sound clueless.
It was something like this:

***Given string as an argument, give us palindrome method that would check if a palindrome of a minimum 3 characters can be created by removing 1 or 2 characters. The string has no special characters, numbers or whitespace basically only letters (eg: str  = "abecbea")
If true, print letters removed, if false print "not possible"***

"remove 1 or 2 characters" and "print letters removed" is giving me a headache legit

I have tried a lot of different things but for the last 2 days but i am completely stuck!
[EDIT]

Ideas i started with below

```
def is_palindrome(s)
  s == s.reverse && s.length >= 3
end

def possible_palin_by_removing_one_char(s)
  array_chars = s.chars
  first_char = array_chars[0]
  last_char = array_chars[-1]

  while first_char < last_char 
    if first_char != last_char
      first_char += 1
      last_char -= 1
    else
      if is_palindrome
        puts ????
      else
        puts "not possible"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

or

```
def palindrome?(string)
  deleted_chars = []
  candidates = 0.upto(string.length-1).map do |index|
    array_chars = string.chars 
    deleted_chars << array_chars.delete_at(index)
    array_chars
  end

  if candidates.any? { |c| c.reverse == c } && string.length >= 3
    puts "It is a palindrome with letters '#{deleted_chars.join(",")}' removed !"
    # puts deleted_chars
  else
    if string.length <= 3
      puts "String '#{string}' is too short"
    else  
      puts "This is not possible to create palindrome with string '#{string}'"
    end
  end
end

palindrome?("abcecbae")
```

I would love someone to help me solve this one
Thanks heaps for your help

Comment: Can you generate each string created by removing one character? Are any of those palindromes? What happens if you run the same test on each of _those_ strings?

Comment: Hi @Chris sorry i am not sure to understand but i would love your help

Answer (score 2):

- Put all chars in an Array (`ar = str.chars`)
- Try all combinations which are 2 less than
  the size of the array (so 5 in the example "abcecbae")(`ar.combination(5)`)
- Select all combinations which happen to be equal to their reverse
- Map the result(s) back from arrays to strings
- Similar for 1 removed char.

Comment: I haven't known about the combination method, great idea!

Comment: Thanks for your input. I haven't thought about combination method either

Answer (score 1):

This task might be a little bit trickier without Ruby's rich standard library support.

Here is how I'd solve this task in the 1st iteration:

1. Check if the original string is a palindrome, return immediately if it is
2. Build a list of possible combinations of indices to remove
3. Iterate over this list, check if removing the chars at given indices makes our input string a palindrome

The trickiest part here is (2), but `Enumerable#permutation` almost does the job.

So, something like

```rb
def palindrome?(s)
  s == s.reverse
end

def indices_to_remove(string)
  ary = (0..string.size-1).to_a
  # Permutations like [0,1] and [1,0] means the same in our context, so we need to remove this duplication.
  (ary.map { |x| [x] } + ary.permutation(2).map(&:sort)).uniq
end

def remove_chars(str, *indices)
  str.dup.tap do |s|
    indices.sort.reverse_each { |i| s[i] = '' }
  end
end

def find_palindrome(str)
  return if palindrome?(str)

  indices_to_remove(str).each do |indices|
    new_str = remove_chars(str, *indices)
    return "Letters removed: #{indices.inspect}; palindrome: '#{new_str}'" if palindrome?(new_str)
  end
end
```

That's it. Let's see if i works:

```
pry(main)> find_palindrome("abecbea")
=> "Letters removed: [1, 3]; palindrome: 'aebea'"
```

It does. Adjust the filtering logic (check palindroms' size as needed) and output if necessary.

Comment: I did not know #permutation. I wasn't sure what was the difference with #combination.
They both return every possible combination or permutation of the elements within that array. The difference between the two is that #permutation treats different orders of the same elements as different combinations, whereas #combination ignores different orders of the same elements, including each combination only once.

Comment: what would you recommend to return letters rather than indices?

Comment: It depends on the task definition, doesn't it? :)

Comment: the assessment was requesting to return letters removed if palindrome, i came up with the below solution

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for your help. With the help of a senior dev, we came up with the below solution

```
def palindrome_check(str)
  length = str.length
  # convert to array of chars
  chars = str.chars

  # check if palindrome by deleting 1 characters
  length.times do |i|
    char = chars.delete_at(i)
    return "Letter '#{char}' has been removed from String '#{str}' to create palindrome" if chars == chars.reverse

    # return the array to original condition
    chars.insert(i, char)
  end

  # only do remove 2 characters check if length > 4, as otherwise removing would result in a string less than 3 characters
  if length > 4
    length.times do |i|
      length.times do |j|
        # avoid repeating the same checks
        next if j <= i
        # since j is always greater than i, remove j first to avoid affecting which character is at position i
        char_two = chars.delete_at(j)
        char_one = chars.delete_at(i)

        return "Letters '#{[char_one, char_two].join(' and ')}' has been removed from String '#{str}' to create palindrome" if chars == chars.reverse

        # return the array to original condition
        chars.insert(i, char_one)
        chars.insert(j, char_two)
      end
    end
  end

  return "'#{str}' can't be a Palindrome"
end
```

```
palindrome_check('string') # 'can't be a Palindrome'
palindrome_check('abcdcfba') # 'f'
palindrome_check('rqubyxyburx') # 'q, x'
```